# cakephp 4 extended model in plugin - table not found

Tags: cakephp, orm, cakephp-4.x

I've problem with extended model. I've 2 models: Users and ExtendedUsers (with custom functions).

My extended model code:

```
class UsersExtendedTable extends UsersTable
{
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        parent::initialize($config);
        $this->setTable('users');
        $this->setEntityClass('UserExtended');
    }
    ...
}
```

The extended model is located in plugin, so I wrote:

```
$this->userTable = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('AdminPanel.UsersExtended');
pr($this->userTable->find()->all());
```

The second line getting an error: "**SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'tablename.users_extended' doesn't exist.**"
even though I'm setting table name in initialize() method.

Could U help ?

Comment: If you check `get_class($this->userTable)` does it say it's your type, or the generic Cake table class? I'm betting it's the latter, and that it'll be because of something about naming somewhere (folder or filename or namespace of your extended table class, most likely).

Comment: @GregSchmidt  Ha! U're right! folder was wrong :) I now it was trivial, but can't find problem!